# How can I vertically center text in a ul navigation-bar without these multiple CSS conflicts?

Tags: css, center, padding, vertical-alignment, navigationbar

I have made a functional CSS navigation-bar, except for some fugly CSS side-effects --
I am trying to vertically center the text in each list block, and `vertical-align: middle` was not working. Instead, I am using `padding-top: 13px`, but this renders the padded area without the `background-color` of the rest of the list element, and the `display: inline block` styling of the link does **not** extend to the padded area either! (`a:hover` is affecting only the area below the padding)
So how can I vertically center text in list elements without these CSS problems?
Here is the relevant CSS:

```
/* header section */
#header
{
    padding-left: 115px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
    #main-menu
    {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    #main-menu li
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 13px;

        color: #666;
        font-family: "Lucida Console";
        font-variant: small-caps;
        letter-spacing: 2px;

        /* for  block layout */
            display: -moz-inline-box; /* for firefox */
            display: inline-block;

        width: 153px;
        height: 32px;
    }
    #main-menu a:link, a:visited
    {
        display: -moz-inline-box; /* for firefox */
        display: inline-block;

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    #main-menu a:hover, a:active
    {
        background-color: #bbb;
    }<br /><br />
```

...and here is the relevant HTML:

```
        <!-- header section -->
        <div id = "header">
            <ul id = "main-menu">
                <!-- no spaces between list elements when all on the same line! -->
                <li><a href = "home.html" title = "home">home</a></li><li><a href = "about.html" title = "about">about</a></li><li><a href = "cart.html" title = "shopping cart">cart</a></li><li><a href = "login.html" title = "log in">login</a></li><li><a href = "createAccount.html" title = "create a new account">sign up</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div> <!-- end of header section -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things that I changed:

- Changed the link to display as a block element.
- Removed the padding at the top of the li elements.
- Added that padding height to the height of the li elements.
- Set the line-height to the height of the li elements.
- Some formatting

http://jsfiddle.net/gtr053/7yrX7/

Comment: Ah! I had tried `margin-top`, but since margin affects the outside (and not the inside) that doesn't work. Getting rid of the padding, and adding `line-height` was the solution, thanks for that. Didn't consider having both `height` and `line-height`, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Yeah, basically you set the height of the element as desired and then you set the line-height to whatever the height is. This only works with one line of text, though (there's exceptions to this that are outside the scope of your needs).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a line height

```
line-height: 13px;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much to anything but I've used this just now and it works

Entered into the Quick CSS of General styling

```
li {
    display:inline;
    padding: 0px 50px;
}
```

The first px brings the menu items down, and the second spreads them apart.